# Adding colorbar to scatter plot

Tags: python, matplotlib, scatter-plot

I am currently working with some geospatial data and I want to add a colorbar next to the map. I used the following code to overlay a baseline map with a scatter plot. However, I cannot get the correct colorbar next to it. Can anyone find the reason for such behaviour?

```
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('RdYlBu') # define a colormap

fig,ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 15))    
city_map = df.plot(alpha=0.2, ax=ax) # plot a city contour
ctx.add_basemap(city_map) # plot a city map

points = gdf_new.plot(c=gdf_new['Score'], cmap=cm, ax=ax) # scatter plot
fig.colorbar(ax.collections[1], ax=ax) # current solution
```

pandas column `gdf_new['Score']` contains values from 0 to 1 used for points coloring.
If I replace the last line with below, I get:

for `plt.colorbar()` - `RuntimeError: No mappable was found to use for colorbar creation. First define a mappable such as an image (with imshow) or a contour set (with contourf)`

for `plt.colorbar(point)` - `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'get_array'`

My current solution is to add:
`fig.colorbar(ax.collections[1], ax=ax)` - it displays the correct color bar but with a wrong numbers' range of 0-200 instead 0-1.

How to fix it?